# Accessing an image stored with FileStorage from a custom template tag in Django

Tags: python, django, file-storage

I have used Django's FileStorage to store an image, and I have sent the url of this image from a template to a custom templatetag. But I am not able to access the image at this url.

I have also tried accessing the media directory to get the uploaded image but I get the following error:
IsADirectoryError at /

[Errno 21] Is a directory: 'media/'

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":

        up_image = request.FILES['image']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        name = fs.save(up_image.name,up_image)
        context['url'] = fs.url(name)

    return render(request,"ind.html",context)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

template ind.html

```
{% load testing %}
    <p>{% fname url %}</p>
```

custom templatetag testing.py

```
from django import template
import webbrowser
from PIL import Image


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag


def fname(url):
    x = url[7:] #getting only the name of the file uploaded
    path = 'media/'+x


    with Image.open(path) as image:
        width, height = image.size
    return width
```

I have also tried opening the image with the url passed itself but I could not get it to work.

I am just trying to access the uploaded image so I can do some further processing for it, but for now I am just returning the width of the image to check if it is working

Comment: > `path = '/media/'+x`

Need set real path to file, not URL path

Comment: "media/test.jpeg" is not real path, use full path. Example, `path = settings.BASE_PATH + '/media/test.jpeg'`

Comment: Thanks, that's great!